# What is the connection between the number of variables and the number of equations in a linear system?

Tags: linear-algebra

Are there any rules for the solution/s of the linear system of equations we can draw if we look at the number of variables and equations?

Answer (score 1):

In general, if there are more equations than variables we call the system "overdetermined" and it almost always has no solution. If there are more variables than equations, we call the system "underdetermined" and the system has either no solution or infinite solutions.